# Get Public IP Address of WinRT device in application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-runtime, winrt-async

I have the need to know the Public IP address of the device on which my app is running.  The application is a Windows Store WinRT/Metro app.

Using: NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile and NetworkInformation.GetHostNames I am able to retrieve the Local IP Address and not the Public.

In the end i have a found http://freegeoip.net/xml/ which is a public REST API for searching geolocation of IP addresses and host names.  But this is not a viable solution, i was wondering if i was missing something? or if there is an easier way?

Comment: Nope, you need to ask something outside your network what address you are presenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to find your external IP address is to use a open service on the internet.

For example this is taken from here: [Getting the external IP address](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/452024/Getting-the-External-IP-Address) but adapted to work in WinRT

```
Task<string> result = GetExternalIP();    
string externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"))
                        .Matches(result.Result)[0].ToString();
......

public async Task<string> GetExternalIP()
{
   HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
   HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync("http://www.realip.info/api/p/realip.php");
   return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

If you try that url directly in your browser you will get a simple HTML page with this content

```
{"IP":"150.37.216.15"}
```

and then the Regex just extract the IP info 150.37.216.15

Comment: Um, that response looks like JSON. You should use a proper JSON parser instead of just grabbing the first thing that looks like an IP address. Because who knows, maybe in the future it will return `{"Route":["74.40.12.186",207.46.45.30"],"IP":"150.37.216.15"}` and you just grabbed the IP address of some intermediate router.

Comment: Yes probably you are right. But, as far as I know, this response has been pretty stable and I am not convinced that they could ever think to change the response to include additional info. And, in the process, risking to break any app that works against that URL. It would be more correct to expose a new url